# Django-crispy-form: add HTML element inside of `Field` class

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

This is default `HTML` structure when using `Field` class of `django-crispy-form`.

```
Field(
    'need_meeting',
    autocomplete='off',
    id='need-meeting',
),
```

**.html**

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <div id="div_id_need_meeting" class="checkbox"> 
        <label for="need-meeting" class=""> 
            <input autocomplete="off" checked="checked" class="checkboxinput" id="need-meeting" name="need_meeting" type="checkbox"> 
             현금영수증 발행 
        </label> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

But what I want to do is to add some elements(`<i></i>`) inside of `label` element like this:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <div id="div_id_need_meeting" class="checkbox"> 
        <label for="need-meeting" class=""> 
            <input autocomplete="off" checked="checked" class="checkboxinput" id="need-meeting" name="need_meeting" type="checkbox"> 
             <i></i>현금영수증 발행 
        </label> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

I have no idea even I searched for 2hours.

Need your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can insert HTML into a form using the [crispy-form-helper](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html)
the tutorial for that seems to be intuitive. I am not pretty good at that, but I am using it a few times, and it helped me to customize the layout.